# iPhone - Where is the [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] file stored on the computer?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

When running an app on the iPhone (for example when you can do it in another way testing some GPS or camera feature), where can I find and check the file created by NSUserDefaults to save the standardUserDefaults ? I'm running XCode 4.

Comment: Who says it's in a file? And why does it matter? There's an API to access the values. How it's implemented should make no difference.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington : It's for easier debug and to see what is really recorded regarding to the original plist given.

Comment: This will give you the location in Swift 3.1: print(NSHomeDirectory())

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**It's in your app directory under**:

> Library -> Preferences -> `bundleID`.plist

You can access the data on your device. 
Go into the organizer select your device then the app and there should be a download button there. If you click that it will download all the app data.

Comment: +1 @rckoenes: Can you provide some more information. I didn't find in my system.

Comment: I don't find this folder in my app directory. For information, I run XCode 4.

Comment: The has nothing to do with XCode 4. See the answer provided by Clawoo

Answer (score 6):

The user defaults file for applications started in the simulator are located here:

`/Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/[UNIQUE IDENTIFIER]/Library/Preferences/APP_ID.plist`

The **USERNAME** is the user you run as on your system.

The **UNIQUE IDENTIFIER** is generated by Xcode.

**APP_ID** is your com.yourcompany.app bundle id.

Comment: @Oliver: This is what you asked for.

Comment: Yes I did, but since you can't access the application bundle from your device from your Mac, I gave you a solution for the Simulator. I suppose you could try to read the contents of the plist from your device using [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:] and figuring out the path to the Library/Preferences/APP_ID.plist file.

Comment: You can access the data ion your device. Go into the organizer selected te your device then the app and there should be a download button there. If you click that it will download all the app data.

Comment: @rckoenes : rckoenes, you Rockkkk !Coudl you please post your comment as an answer as I could accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can see it in:**

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F27682C5-55AC-4984-9864-313DA609134F/Library/Preferences
>   while App at:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/AE02FFCA-4CAF-4B58-8F32-0D67A78BD259