# iOS - Where is object stored in application NSUserDefault?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I am using NSUserDefault in my application most of the times but I can't find where it's storing the object (storing means it's there in app somewhere). I googled it but couldn't find the location. Where it is stored? Thank you!

Comment: It's on _your apps location/Library/Preferences_.

Comment: iRajulu Check My answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very exact answer is

> CoreSimulator/Devices/->device id<-/data/Library/Preferences

[Where is NSUserDefault storing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065694/where-is-plist-file-storing-nsuserdefaults-in-xcode-6)

[NSUserDefault Stored in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340485/where-are-user-defaults-plist-files-stored-in-ios8)

[Where is the [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] file stored on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403807/iphone-where-is-the-nsuserdefaults-standarduserdefaults-file-stored-on-the-c)

Comment: Thanks for more information @user3182143

Comment: If it works kindly accept it because others can get the solution through your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Library/Preferences
>   /Users/tomhsu/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/835DED9B-A3FE-4E77-ABD6-A198E0940243/Library/Preferences/xxxxxxx.plist

Use [this](http://simpholders.com/) for open it

Comment: Who said anything about the Simulator?

Comment: Outside the simulator nobody cares where it is stored, because you can't access it anyway.